# Will mirabelles grow and fruit in Northern England?

Tags: fruit-trees, plums

Plums can fruit pretty prolifically up here in NE England but we can get frosts quite late into spring and this has to be taken into account choosing varieties of fruit trees.

I understand mirabelles flower quite early, but are their flowers at significant frost risk like apple blossom? Are they suited to growing in the UK outside of southern regions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal condition for growing mirabelle plums is indeed found farther to the south. It is suited to a northern Mediterranean climate, with France and Spain being significant producers. They also prefer bright, sunny weather for the fruits to reach their level of deliciousness. So, the two hindrances for growing them in northern England are relatively cooler climate and relatively less sunlit days.

That being said, mirabelle plants are robust, and as mentioned in the question description, other plums proliferate quite well in northern England. So, mirabelles are also certain to survive there. But they may not be as prolific as in farther south.